# Cypher query to return a set of all the relationships that A is involved in

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a database like:

```
    A       F
   / \       \
  B   C       G
 /
D
```

I would like a set of all relations that A is involved in.  This query is the best I can do, but returns all pairs of nodes in A's graph, with shared relationships repeated:

```
START start = node(A) 
MATCH (start)-[rel*]->(child)
RETURN rel, child;
```

How best to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I needed something like this (suggested by [Peter Neubauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83490/peter-neubauer)):

```
START s = node:node_auto_index(name="A") 
MATCH (s)-[:CHILD*0..]->(parent),        
      path=(parent)-[:CHILD]->(child),       
      (child)-[:CHILD*0..]->(leaf) 
WHERE NOT leaf-[:CHILD]->() 
WITH DISTINCT path AS path 
RETURN EXTRACT(n IN NODES(path): n.name)
```

Sketched up [on the neo4j website](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=jelpnu).

A more succinct version:

```
START s = node:node_auto_index(name="A") 
MATCH (s)-[:CHILD*0..]-( ss ),
      path = ( ss )-[:CHILD]->(child) 
WITH DISTINCT path AS path 
RETURN EXTRACT(n IN NODES(path): n.name)
```